# "トムと話した" vs. "トムと話し合った"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824825837) *(Chap. 29)* says that for some verbs which can be unilateral or bilateral (like `相談する`, `話す`, `合う`),

The particle `と` implies that the verb is shared 50/50 between the two participants (bilateral), whereas the particle `に` implies that the main (or only) person doing the action is the subject (unilateral):

[image]

For example:

> ジョンがトムに話した。 (John talked to Tom)
>
> ジョンがトムと話した。 (John talked with Tom)
>
> ジョンがトムに相談した。 (John consulted Tom)
>
> ジョンがトムと相談した。 (John consulted with Tom)

I was wondering since `ジョンがトムと話した。` already implies that it is a bilateral action, what is the difference in nuance between `ジョンがトムと話した。` and `ジョンがトムと話し合った。`?

Comment: ジョンがトムと相談した and ジョンがトムに喧嘩した are ungrammatical.

Comment: @sawa hmm weird I didn't invent the と相談する example. I got it from http://www.amazon.com/Making-Sense-Japanese-Grammar-Paper/dp/0824825837

Comment: The question is about 話し合った, so why do you list a bunch of examples that have nothing to do with the question?  I mean, I eventually see where you're going with it, but it's a very roundabout way to do it, and confusing as you're reading through the question.

Comment: @istrasci ok I've done some touchup, is the question still confusing?

Comment: Yeah, a lot better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A が B に ...` means A did something **to** B (asymmetrically). The verb must be something that one does to another:

> ジョンがトムに相談した。
>   　'John asked Tom for suggestion.'
>   × ジョンがトムに喧嘩した。
>   　'John fought (to) Tom.'
>   　ジョンがトムに話しかけた。
>   　'John talked to Tom.'
>   × ジョンがトムに話し合った。
>   　'John conversed (to) Tom.'

`A と B が ...` or `A が B と ...` means A and B did something **with** each other (symmetrically). The verb must be something that a group of people do with one another.

> × ジョンがトムと相談した。
>   　'John asked with Tom for suggestion.'
>   　ジョンがトムと喧嘩した。
>   　'John fought with Tom.'
>   × ジョンがトムと話しかけた。
>   　'John talked to with Tom.'
>   　ジョンがトムと話し合った。
>   　'John conversed with Tom.'

`話す` as well as `talk` has two meanings. One includes the meaning of 'start', and the other does not. The former is asymmetric and the latter is not. That is why both forms can be used.

> ジョンがトムに話した。
>   　'John talked to Tom.'
>   　ジョンがトムと話した。
>   　'John talked with Tom.'

Comment: The x besides the sentence demarks an incorrect sentence?

Comment: @sawa what's the difference between using 「と話し合った」 and using 「と話した」 ?

Comment: @Pacerier `合う` when used in compound verb means 'mutally'. `かける` means 'start' or 'attempt'.

Comment: @sawa hey thanks but I'm still quite confused about the difference. Isn't 「ジョンがトムと話した」 also a mutual action?

Comment: @Pacerier `話した` is ambiguous between mutual action and one-way action. Adding `合う` disambiguates it so that the one-way meaning will not be allowed any more.

Comment: @sawa hey thanks I think that clarifies it =D

Comment: @sawa Now that I look at it again, I was wondering if "と" is already symmetric, doesn't it mean that `と話した` is already non-ambiguous?